# python: I need to insert a text box into the txtbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a new guy who is not familiar with python language. I am working on app that shows a match scores and it ranks the players. However, I am stuck when it comes with GUI, what I've done so far I created two taps one for the ladies and one for men. I am wondering if I could within the tabs to insert a textbox and the textbox is linked to a button when I press button it shows the file's content.

```
## this is the code 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).grid(row=0, column=0)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')

# Adds Men tab
men = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(men, text='Men')

# Adds Ladies tab
ladies = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(ladies, text='Ladies')

    enter code here

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is _the file_?

Comment: A csv file that has the 4 columns : "player A, playerA sets, playerB, playerB sets"

Answer (score 1):

Below code creates a Text widget under `ladies` tab and when `Read` button is pressed the contents of a csv file, `"theFile.csv"` is put into the Text widget. A similar piece can be written for the other tab as well.

```
import csv
def put_file():
    with open('theFile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

        for row in spamreader:
            textL.insert("1.0", ', '.join(row))


textL = Text(ladies)
textL.pack()
Button(ladies, text="Read", command=put_file).pack()
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked fine one more thing if i want for example to print out specific columns and i want to show them next to each other should i add a code to textL.insert?